# Function is not not working inside PHP mail body

Tags: php, wordpress, function, email

I'm using this to send a basic email:

```
// Email details
$name = 'Davo';
$recipient = 'info@davo.com';
$from = 'sender@example.com'
$subject = 'Testing';

// All plugins
function the_plugins() {
    $the_plugs = get_option('active_plugins'); 
    foreach($the_plugs as $key => $value) { 
        $string = explode('/',$value); print $string[0] . '<br />';
    }
}

// Message
$body = '<p>Hello' . $name . ',</p>';
$body .= '<p>Your website has these plugins:</p>';
$body .= the_plugins();
$body .= '<p>Have a nice day.</p>';

$headers[]  = 'Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8';
$headers[]  = 'From' . $name. ' <' . $from . '>';
$headers[]  = 'Reply-To: ' . $from;
$headers[]  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
wp_mail($recipient, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

The only things that does not work is `the_plugins()` function does not show anything in the email that arrives. Instead it's just empty in the line where I expect to see the list of plugins, and looks like this:

```
Hello Davo,
Your website has these plugins:

Have a nice day.
```

FYI `the_plugins()` function works. I am able to `echo the_plugins(); exit;` right after the function and it returns a list of the plugins, so the function itself is not the problem.

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: Return string from function. And remove print statement.

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh do you mean like this: `return $string = explode('/',$value); print $string[0] . '<br />';`

If I do that, it returns `Array`

Comment: I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
function the_plugins() {
    $the_plugs = get_option('active_plugins'); 
    $plugins = '';
    foreach($the_plugs as $key => $value) { 
        $string = explode('/',$value); 
        $plugins .= $string[0] . '<br />';
    }
   return $plugins;
}
```